# Laravel display product by category

Tags: php, laravel

Web Route

```
Route::get('/categories/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'categories'])->name('categories');
```

ProductController

```
public function categories($id)
    {
        $categories = Category::with('product')->find($id);

        return view('products.categories')->with('products', $categories);
    }
```

When returning the `$categories`, it displays the category with selected product (Gaming Chair: Ranger Gaming Chair)

```
{"id":4,"category":"Gaming Chair","created_at":"2021-06-27T16:04:27.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-06-27T16:04:27.000000Z","product":[{"id":2,"category_id":4,"product_name":"Ranger Gaming Chair","description":"Lorem Ipsum","product_picture":"1624846316.png","price":4325.23,"created_at":"2021-06-28T02:11:56.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-06-28T02:11:56.000000Z"}]}
```

But every time I return to view('products.categories') and doing foreach loop

```
@foreach($categories as $item)
  <h5>{{ $item->category }}</h5>
  <h5>{{ $item->product_name }}</h5>
@endforeach
```

It displays the whole category, not the `"Gaming Chair" :/`

Please help me display it.

Comment: It displays an ErrorException
Trying to get property 'category' of non-object

Comment: I didn't get an error but it displays nothing

Comment: Oof... Your code is all over the place. Why is your method called `categories` (plural) when you're only going to get a single `Category` using `->find($id)`? Does each `Category` only have a single `Product`? Cause that's what's suggested by `::with('product')` (should probably be `products`). `{{ $item->category }}` will output everything, since that returns a `Category` instance. Did you mean `$item->category->name`? Etc etc. Lot's of things to fix here.

Comment: yes i'm only going to get single category.
each category have many products.
$item->category->category(the category name) doesnt work :/ it throws errorexception

Comment: Well, `$categories` is an instance of `Category` (again, bad variable name). `$category->category` would output the name, `@foreach($category->products as $product) {{ $product->name }} @endforeach` would output the name of each `Product`, but only if you fix your variable naming.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

**in your controller**

```
    public function categories($id)
        {
           //make this variable singular not plural..its easier to read/understand
            $category = Category::with('product')->find($id); 
    
            return view('products.categories')->with('products', $categories);
        }
```

and **in your blade**

```
@foreach($category->products as $item)
  <h5>{{ $item->category_id }}</h5>
  <h5>{{ $item->product_name }}</h5>
@endforeach
```

Comment: ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() it shows this error sir.

Comment: @NeilNyx Cause you named your relationship `product`, not `products`... `@foreach($category->product as $product) ...` would work, **or you could fix your variable/method naming**.